# YouTube is not available as a Google Apps service on my domain

Tags: google-workspace, youtube

When I visit YouTube, there's a `Sign in` link but when I click it, I'm informed that:

> YouTube has not been enabled by the administrator of the domain @(mydomain).

YouTube itself is fully available; it's not like I'm living in North Korea. But I can't sign up...!

- I am logged into my Google Apps account. I do not have a non-Apps Google account or Gmail address (at least none that I use).
- I have already checked in the Admin Panel (Organization&Users > Services) whether YouTube is `on` or `off`, but it's completely absent.
- I have also checked (in Domain Settings>General) that new services are automatically added.
- I've followed the tips in this [Google Support page](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1074205) which says to check the bottom of the YouTube pages to check what countries YouTube is available in. Lots of European countries are listed, but both Denmark and Austria are notably missing:
  [image]

It appears that the last part above is the problem. What determines the "country" that YouTube uses? Can I switch my Google Apps settings somehow to enable YouTube on my Google Apps?

Comment: Are you already logged into a google account? Gmail?

Comment: I am logged into my Google Apps account. I do not have a non-Apps account.

Answer (score 8):

YouTube is not available  for Google Apps customers in Denmark (and other countries).

The solution is to create a seperate gmail.com account that you use for YouTube.

You can then link the two accounts, and be signed in on both accounts on the same time.

To link the accounts, goto google.com and sign in with your new "for youtube only" account.

In the upper right corner select the dropdown arrow and click "Add account".
Now you can link it to your Google Apps account.

Now go to youtube.com, and you should be signed in with the new account.

On gmail.com and Google.com you can change the active account in the same fly out window you used to link the two profiles.

Last year there was a way to get through the problem. If you signed in with your Google Apps profile in the YouTube app on an Android phone, your account would be validated, and it would also work on a regular PC after this validation, but they have closed this bug now.