# Why can't I enable YouTube as a service on my Google Apps Free account?

Tags: youtube, google-workspace, g-suite-administrator

I am trying to enable YouTube for the users, but the YouTube service is not showing as a service on my Google Apps Free account. Screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of the Google Apps services control panel]

Clicking "here" to add more **Google services does also not show Youtube.** Also searching does not show YouTube.

Because it's a free account, Google [says](http://contact.googleapps.com/?&rd=1):

- Phone support - Not available for your free edition of Google Apps.
- Email support - Not available for your free edition of Google Apps.

What can I do to enable YouTube for my Google Apps users?

Comment: So you can't see "Youtube" under the additional services column? It is listed there, not in Core Google Services. If it is also not there, most likely Youtube isn't available for your country or something.

Comment: Possibly related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29615/youtube-is-not-available-as-a-google-apps-service-on-my-domain?rq=1

Comment: In which country is the domain registered? It could be a similar issue as this - http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/apps/NOhPgEqCHPk/Z6h33B3E3WoJ

Answer (score 2):

Since this is still an issue in 2019, below is the link I used to enable YouTube for an old Google Apps (Free) account. The link takes you to the service status settings for YouTube in your Google Apps admin panel.

https://admin.google.com/ac/settings/serviceonoff?iid=118

Comment: This is almost a link only answer which are not allowed on this site. Please add the most relevant parts or a summary of the linked resource.

Comment: The comment about a link being invalid is not correct. The link is to the YouTube access control portion of the needed admin control program at google.com. The link to the tool is actually the answer itself, not the text within it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

1. At the bottom of the admin console page, click *More controls*.
2. Add the *Other Google services* link to your console by dragging it up.
3. Click *Other Google services* and enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Once I log into the Google Admin Console I was able to manually got the URL:

[https://admin.google.com/AdminHome#AppDetails:service=Youtube](https://admin.google.com/AdminHome#AppDetails%3aservice=Youtube)

and activate YouTube in the drop down menu just underneath the YouTube logo